# Angular - Provide guards across different modules

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-module, angular-router-guards

Basically I have the following Angular modules at the moment:

1. `landing`
2. `admin`
3. `core`
4. `shared`

What I would like is to register a new guard called `AuthenticationGuard` within the `shared` module and provide it accross the different modules.

At the moment it only works, if I register the guard within the `landing-module` (which is the one I bootstrap) and neither if I register it in the `admin.module` or `shared.module`.

If I do that, I receive an error stating the following:

[image]

The registration of the `guard` is done via `providers` array of the corresponding modules.

My goal is to be able to use it across all modules.

There was no issue to inject a service from an the `core` within the `admin` module - so I assume there must be a difference between `guards` and `services` over all?

Currently some of the relevant files look like that (shortened for the sake of brevity):

### landing.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LandingRoutingModule } from './landing.routing.module';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { CoreModule } from '../core/core.module';
import { SecurityModule } from '../security/security.module';
import { AdminModule } from '../admin/admin.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    SecurityModule,
    LandingRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### landing.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'
import { NotFoundComponent } from './../shared/components/not-found/not-found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path : '',
    redirectTo : '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path : 'admin',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    component: NotFoundComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true }
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})

export class LandingRoutingModule { }
```

### admin.module

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';

import { AdminLandingComponent } from './admin-landing/admin- 
landing.component'
import { AdminChildComponent } from './admin-child/admin-child.component'
import { AdminRoutingModule } from './admin.routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminLandingComponent,
    AdminChildComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule
  ],
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

### admin.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AdminLandingComponent } from './admin-landing/admin- 
landing.component';
import { AdminChildComponent } from './admin-child/admin-child.component';

import { AuthenticationGuard } from '../shared/guards/auth-guard.service'

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLandingComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                children: [
                    { path: 'child', component: AdminChildComponent }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
})

export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

### shared.module

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { NotFoundComponent } from './components/not-found/not- 
found.component'
import { AuthenticationGuard } from './guards/auth-guard.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotFoundComponent,  
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
})

export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [AuthenticationGuard]
    };
  }
}
```

### auth-guard.service

```
import { Injectable }               from '@angular/core';
import {
    CanActivate, Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot,
    CanActivateChild,
    NavigationExtras,
    CanLoad,
    Route
}                                   from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService }    from '../../core/services/authentication-service/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {

    constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.canActivate(route, state);
    }

    canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, where and how is the guard provided in the shared module? Post its definition.

Comment: what about AuthenticationService, did you add it to providers arrays? and in which module?

Comment: good input - I've added it to the topic. I've added the implementation of the `guard ` and  `shared ` module.

Comment: @HansMusterWhatElse as Fateh indicated: you're not providing AuthenticationService anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the `AuthenticationService` in your module decorator in the `providers` array. That is what that error is indicating!

Based on what you have here, I do not see `AuthenticationService` added as a provider in any of your modules. Unless it is in your `app.modules.ts` which isn't displayed here.

Comment: For some reason I thought the error mentioned the `AuthenticationGuard` - I will have a look at that!